# ruby keep excute my method eventhough I did not put it in a loop

Tags: ruby, repeat

- Hello, so I am writing a chess game on the console, I have this method "play" and inside it I have 2 loops. When I use "return" to exit the method, the method kept being executed.
- Below is part of my code. I marked the two lines that you needed to notice with "####################".
- So when this condition "count % 3 == 0 && serialize? " is true, it is supposed to stop the program and exit, however, it executed method "introduce" again and that method does not even in a loop. Can anyone please help me ? Thank you very much.

```rb
class Game
  def play
    if introduce == 'c' ####################
      unserialize
    else
      @white.pieces = @white.create_new_pieces
      @black.pieces = @black.create_new_pieces
    end
    set_up
    loop do
      board.display
      player = count.even? ? @white : @black
      opponent = count.even? ? @black : @white

      return if count % 3 == 0 && serialize? ###########################

      loop do
        move = get_move(player) #[piece, postion, destination]
        next if move.nil?
        piece = move[0]
        position = move[1]
        destination = move[2]
        if piece.name == 'K'
          next if is_eaten_by(opponent.pieces, destination).length > 0
          if piece.path_valid?(board, destination)
            change(piece, position, destination, opponent)
            piece.castle = false
          else
            next unless player.check_castle? && castle_succeed?(player, piece, destination)
          end
        else
          player_king_coor = player.get_piece('K')[0].position
          if piece.name == 'p'
            pawn_move = pawn_valid_move(piece, position, destination, opponent)
            next unless pawn_move
            change(piece, position, destination, opponent, pawn_move)
            if is_eaten_by(opponent.pieces, player_king_coor).length > 0
              undo(piece, position, destination, opponent)
              next
            end
            pawn_promote(player, piece)
          else
            next unless piece.path_valid?(board, destination)
            piece.castle = false if piece.name == 'R'
            change(piece, position, destination, opponent)
            if is_eaten_by(opponent.pieces, player_king_coor).length > 0
              undo(piece, position, destination, opponent)
              next
            end
          end
        end
        break
      end
      modify_in_passing(player)
      result = is_checkmated?(player, opponent)
      result = tie?(player, opponent) unless result
      if result != false
        annouce_result(result)
        board.display
        break
      end
      @count += 1
    end
  end

  def introduce
    puts 'Welcome to the game!'
    unless File.zero?('./lib/saved_game.yml')
      loop do
        puts "Press 'n' if you want to play new game and 'c' if you want to continue previous game"
        answer = gets.chomp.strip
        return answer if answer == 'n' || answer == 'c'
        puts "Please enter a valid answer!"
      end
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new
game.play
```

I tried to add a "puts" after the condition "if count % 3 == 0 && serialize?" and it was not printed. And I also tried to reproduce the problem by making a simple class and method with loop and everything works fine.
I use Vscode.

Comment: this is impossible to answer without a reproducible example. `puts` has done as much as it could here, time to learn a bit of debugging https://github.com/ruby/debug#how-to-use. `require "debug"`, add breakpoint `debugger`, commands: `step`, `next`, `continue` and `help`, `info`.

Comment: I agree, there isn't enough evidence in your code to debug it. Try slowly removing parts of your program until you have a very simple example that reproduces the issue and then update your question to include that whole executable example.